# Correlation scatter plot using DataFrame matrix?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following pandas dataframe:

Here's the csv format for it:

https://ghostbin.com/paste/c2jzb

Here's what it looks after I used .corr() on the variable holding the data

[image]

I need to be able to make a **correlation** scatter plot with this dataframe, using matplotlib. I have no idea were to begin.

This is my code so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas
from pandas.plotting import scatter_matrix


df_oz = pandas.read_csv("file.csv")
dfCorr = df_oz.corr()
pandas.plotting.scatter_matrix(dfCorr)
plt.show()
```

Which gives me the following result:

[image]

However, this scatter plot seems unorganized, the grid marking the values are not visibles and overall looks off, I don't know what I'm doing wrong

**Also, is there a way using a matplotlib solution instead of pandas?**

Comment: What do you expect the result to look like?

Comment: Why there's multiple points in each variable pair? Shouldn't it be just one point? 
Also, the 0 and 1 axis in each grid its different. I'd like for them to all have the same 1 and 0 position

Comment: You can fine-tune the aesthetics with matplotlib and also use a shared x axis there. But please explain a bit more what you mean by *correlation scatter plot*. We don't know what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @cripcate As you can see in the correlated dataframe, the first pair of values is ozone and ozone, and its value is one, so in the first grid, a dot should represent 1 value by a single dot being in 1.  If same with the second item in the first row of the dataframe, you see its value is 0.38, so in the second scatter a dot should be between 0 and 1, representing 0.38, and so on and so forth with all the pairs. I don't want for every scatter to have multiple points each.

Comment: Why would you then draw a single scatter plot for each point? Wouldn’t it make more sense to a) plot all the points with a regression line + r^2-value (correlation)? Or b) plot all the single dots in one scatter plot with labels.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matplotlib to plot a pairplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56188305/matplotlib-to-plot-a-pairplot)